# Use JYETech 2.4 Inch LCD Display Screen Module with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, lcd, pins, tft

I have this JYETech 2.4 Inch LCD Display Screen Module that I would like to use for a project I have in mind, however, I'm not sure how to wire it up with my Arudino Mega. [Here is the datasheet for the display](https://jyetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/dso138-schematic-lcd.pdf). I have also attached a picture of the display below. The display is meant to work with a DIY oscilloscope but according to the manufacturer and other forum posts, it can be used as a display with other projects as well.

[Pictures of the display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ3FC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

That display is an ILI9341 based one. On the DSO138 it connects the data pins D0-D7 to PORTB of the STM32.

You need to connect those 8 pins to 8 pins on the Arduino, along with the RS (Register Select) and CS (Chip Select) pins. The RD pin can be connected to 3.3V and the WR pin to GND, since you only really want to write to the screen (if you do want to read from the screen then you will want to connect RD and WR to two IO pins as well). Reset can be connected to a GPIO or to 3.3V, depending on if you want to do a hard reset at any point or not.

LED-A can connect to 5V, and each of the LED-K* pins should connect to ground through a resistor each. The size of the resistor will set the backlight brightness (try 100Ω to start with).

Then it's just a matter of finding a library that works with the ILI9341 in 8-bit parallel mode (u8glib maybe? I don't know, I never use Arduino to drive a TFT).

Note that since this is a 3.3V device you should really use a level shifter for all the digital signals.

Comment: the ILI9341 has a serial interface available